# Getting price before and after discount separately using nokogiri n Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, nokogiri

I'm trying to learn on scrap these values which i put it in 2 different task:

1. get the 35.00 from the entire text
2. get the 42.00 from the entire text

below is the html:

```
<p style="font-size: 30px; margin-left: -10px; padding: 15px 0pt;">
$35.00 - $42.00
</p>
```

the code that im using to get the entire text is as below:

```
node = html_doc.at_css('p')  
p node.text
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the whole text from `node.text` and that's as far as you need to go with Nokogiri. From there you could use [`scan`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-scan) to find the numbers and a bit of list wrangling ([`flatten`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-flatten) and [`map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-map)) and you're done. Something like this:

```
first, second = node.text.scan(/(\d+(?:\.\d+))/).flatten.map(&:to_f)
```

That should leave you with 35.0 in `first` and `42.0` in `second`. If you know that the numbers are prices with decimals then you can simplify the regex a bit:

```
first, second = node.text.scan(/(\d+\.\d+)/).flatten.map(&:to_f)
```

Comment: a very clear explanation with example,thanks mate..let me try it out :D

Answer (score 1):

mu's answer is correct but it seems simpler to use split/splat.

```
first, second = *node.text.tr('$', '').split(' - ')
```